# mysql select across 2 tables - only include rows from 1 if match value in another

Tags: php, mysql

I've built a maintenance database for a client with multiple tables that works fine, but now they want to be able to get reports and I'm having trouble creating a select statement across 2 tables.

A user can search repair type, start/end date and location...no issue at all returning results of repair type between 2 dates (all held in the same table), but the tables for different types of repair don't store the location info, that is held against info in the vehicle info table.

So on 1 table I can query something like:

```
SELECT fid from cm_repair where start_date >= '$date1' AND end_date <= '$date2'
```

and on the other table I can have:

```
SELECT id from cm_fleet where location='$loc'
```

Is there anyway I can combine these so that I only get rows where id and fid match?

Comment: You need to learn about [JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)s

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT fid 
from cm_repair as t1
join cm_fleet as t2 on t1.fid = t2.id and location='$loc'
where start_date >= '$date1' AND end_date <= '$date2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins).

Inner, left, and right join's are common options for combining tables that you might be needing here.

Inner will bring in all valid rows and selected columns from BOTH tables. Essentially if the ID you are joining is present in one table, but not the other, you could end up with columns with null values.

Left and right are similar and a bit faster at processing than the Inner since less data is returned (depending on your query and statements). Essentially it'll return all valid rows and selected columns from the left and right table, BUT if the ID that you are joining on is not in the other side of the join, that row of data will not be returned, therefore no null values.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, will try all this - however we've discovered a flaw in the way the tables are setup anyway and need to edit to include a location column in the repair table, so that will make it all much easier to search as well.